# How the following equality true?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm reading a lemma's proof, and the proof starts with:

> Let $\alpha \in \text{arg}(\int^b_af(t)dt)$:
> $$
> \Bigg|\int^b_af(t)dt\Bigg|=e^{-i \alpha}\int^b_af(t)dt
> $$

I know that $z=r\cdot e^{i\alpha}$ and $|z|=r$, but idk how to related those things to the previous equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z=r\cdot e^{i\alpha}$ then $e^{-i\alpha}z=e^{-i\alpha}\cdot r\cdot e^{i\alpha}=r(e^{-i\alpha}e^{i\alpha})=re^{-i\alpha+i\alpha}=re^0=r=|z|.$